# Undefined array key ""

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование

Смотрел видеоурок [Laravel 9 и Vue 3 SPA интернет магазин 7. CRUD по пользователям](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhXHg-A1ORw&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t9UEjGQHafQB751mf5cwqNv&index=9) с 9:00-10:50. Получаю следующую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу код

laravelvue3shop\app\Models\User.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    const GENDER_MALE=1;
    const GENDER_FEMALE=2;

    protected $table='users';
    protected $guarded=false;

    static function getGenders() {
        return [
           self::GENDER_MALE => 'Мужской',
           self::GENDER_FEMALE => 'Женский'
        ];
    }

    public function getGenderTitleAttribute() {
        return self::getGenders()[$this->gender];
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

laravelvue3shop\database\migrations\2022_09_07_084830_add_surname_patronymic_age_address_gender_to_users_table.php

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->string('patronymic')->nullable();
            $table->integer('age')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedSmallInteger('gender')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('gender');
            $table->dropColumn('address');
            $table->dropColumn('age');
            $table->dropColumn('patronymic');
            $table->dropColumn('surname');
        });
    }
};
```

laravelvue3shop/resources/views/user/create.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0">Добавить пользователя</h1>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Главная</li>
                    </ol>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
                <form action="{{ route('user.store') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("name") }}" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" value="{{ old("email") }}" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("password") }}" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("password_confirmation") }}" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" placeholder="Подтверждение пароля">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("surname") }}" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("patronymic") }}" name="patronymic" class="form-control" placeholder="Отчество">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("age") }}" name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Возраст">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ old("address") }}" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Адрес">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="gender" class="custom-select form-control" id="exampleSelectBorder">
                            <option disabled selected>Пол</option>
                            <option {{ old('gender') == 1 ? ' selected' : '' }} value="1">Мужской</option>
                            <option {{ old('gender') == 2 ? ' selected' : '' }} value="2">Женский</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Добавить">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
@endsection
```

laravelvue3shop/resources/views/user/edit.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h1 class="m-0">Редактировать пользователя</h1>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Главная</li>
                    </ol>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
            <div class="row">
                <form action="{{ route('user.update', $user->id) }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('patch')
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ $user->name ?? old("name") }}" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ $user->surname ?? old("surname") }}" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ $user->patronymic ?? old("patronymic") }}" name="patronymic" class="form-control" placeholder="Отчество">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ $user->age ?? old("age") }}" name="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Возраст">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" value="{{ $user->address ?? old("address") }}" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Адрес">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="gender" class="custom-select form-control" id="exampleSelectBorder">
                            <option disabled selected>Пол</option>
                            <option {{ $user->gender == 1 || old('gender') == 1 ? ' selected' : '' }} value="1">Мужской</option>
                            <option {{ $user->gender == 2 || old('gender') == 2 ? ' selected' : '' }} value="2">Женский</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Добавить">
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
@endsection
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибка в обращении к `$this->gender`.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->gender`  - пустой. Соответственно конструкция `self::getGenders()[$this->gender]` не работает, так как в массиве нет ключа с пустым значением

Comment: в $this->gender лежит значение, которое вводится в `laravelvue3shop/resources/views/user/create.blade.php` в select-е. Оно не пустое.

Comment: оно пустое........как минимум сам текст ошибки говорит об этом....... если хочется убедиться в этом - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482 вот отладочка в помощь

Comment: при выборе значения в `<option disabled selected>Пол</option>`  что будет в переменной? какое значение?

Comment: также стоит обратить внимание, что из формы прилетают строковые значения, а в ключах массива - числа